# rm -rf return codes

Tags: shell, unix

Any one can let me know the possible return codes for the command **rm -rf** other than zero i.e, possible return codes for failure cases.
I want to know more detailed reason for the failure of the command unlike just the command is failed(return other than 0).

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ I'm actually surprised that the rm manpage doesn't describe the possible exit status codes.  If you `man ls` on Ubuntu, it explains the reason for nonzero exit status

Comment: Its a value greater than 0 . In case of error.

Comment: I disagree with the migration from SO, since the OP is interested in the return codes it is very likely that this is a scripting/programming kind of issue.

Comment: by the way, i am interest at the number of scenario it can return. Will it be OS dependent ?

Comment: kinda pissed about the migration myself... almost got the reversal achievement =P

Answer (score 9):

To see the return code, you can use `echo $?` in bash.

To see the actual meaning, some platforms (like Debian Linux) have the `perror` binary available, which can be used as follows:

```
$ rm -rf something/; perror $?
rm: cannot remove `something/': Permission denied
OS error code   1:  Operation not permitted
```

`rm -rf` automatically suppresses most errors.  The most likely error you will see is `1` (Operation not permitted), which will happen if you don't have permissions to remove the file.  `-f` intentionally suppresses most errors

Comment: +1 for mentioning `perror`. On my system it ships with mysql.

Comment: might have better luck with strace in terms of diagnostics.

Comment: @MattJoyce `strace` tells you if a system call fails, but unless you look at the source you don't know how the syscall relates to the program exit status (for example, if you run in `-f`, `ENOENT` is suppressed).  Hence that's not relevant here

Comment: try `rm -rfv ...`  Its called verbose for a reason.

Comment: the logic flow is readily apparent with strace and fairly comprehensive.  something like an operation not permitted would be yielded.

Comment: @technosaurus the `-v` flag only tells you the files that were actually deleted.  It doesn't tell you about errors (the `-f` suppresses most errors)

Comment: @MattJoyce there's a difference between the syscall failing and the program reporting an error, and the question is asking about the program exit status.

Comment: True.  Mind you looking at the source for rm... there really is not much going on there.

Comment: @Nirk - that seems utterly useless, logical behavior would be to change "Error" to "Warning" if both -f and -v are passed, but the busybox implementation is the same (easy to patch though)

Comment: @technosaurus to be absolutely clear, `-v` is nonstandard.  On OSX the manpage explicitly says "The -v option is non-standard and its use in scripts is not recommended."

Comment: @Nirk, my assumption was that it was simply for debugging, not app inclusion to use the output, if that is the case I could only recommend patching the source (as per my comment in Matt Joyce's answer) since the exit codes provide nothing useful with -f ticked

Comment: @technosaurus the point of the `-v` was to indicate what files were actually removed.  `rm -f foo bar baz` won't tell you if `bar` was removed or if it didn't exist in the first place.  `rm -vf foo bar baz` will explicitly tell you which files were deleted.  There's a practical use for it -- it's not just for debugging.

Comment: In order not to install MySQL for `perror`, I found one in Python: https://gist.github.com/mtornwall/2703885

Answer (score 4):

grabbed coreutils from git....

looking at exit we see...

```
openfly@linux-host:~/coreutils/src $ cat rm.c | grep -i exit
  if (status != EXIT_SUCCESS)
  exit (status);
  /* Since this program exits immediately after calling 'rm', rm need not
  atexit (close_stdin);
          usage (EXIT_FAILURE);
        exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
          usage (EXIT_FAILURE);
        error (EXIT_FAILURE, errno, _("failed to get attributes of %s"),
        exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
  exit (status == RM_ERROR ? EXIT_FAILURE : EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

Now looking at the status variable....

```
openfly@linux-host:~/coreutils/src $ cat rm.c | grep -i status
usage (int status)
  if (status != EXIT_SUCCESS)
  exit (status);
  enum RM_status status = rm (file, &x);
  assert (VALID_STATUS (status));
  exit (status == RM_ERROR ? EXIT_FAILURE : EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

looks like there isn't much going on there with the exit status.

I see EXIT_FAILURE and EXIT_SUCCESS and not anything else.

so basically 0 and 1 / -1

To see specific exit() syscalls and how they occur in a process flow try this

```
openfly@linux-host:~/ $ strace rm -rf $whatever
```

fairly simple.

ref:

http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/EXIT_FAILURE/exit/

Comment: Do not understand why, +1 from me. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/rm.html) also only really says `0 / >0`.

Comment: While this may be partially right it does not answer the OP question `I want to know more detailed reason for the failure of the command unlike just the command is failed(return other than 0)` so the down votes are understandable.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth EXIT_FAILURE is 1: "On POSIX systems, the value of this macro is 1" (http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html)

Comment: Adrian the ref for EXIT_FAILURE is there and even the linux manpage for it suggests it can be different on other platforms.  so i figured i'd suggest that as well.

Comment: @Matt Isn't that exactly what I said? That it *can* be different based on the `rm` specification not explicitly listing any specific exit statues, hence my upvote. @Nirk And, yes, `EXIT_FAILURE` is `1` on POSIX systems, but `rm` does not need to exit with the `EXIT_FAILURE` macro. `rm` *could* return >1 and still be POSIX-compliant according to the tool's specification. So, the question cannot really be answered other than "`>0` is some kind of error" and anything more is up to the implementation.

Comment: Probably =P  I was just trying to provide clarification.  Seems this question is bringing all the angry grey beards to the yard and I don't want to offend them anymore than I already have.

Comment: Haha, fair enough :-) Just to be clear, your answer is correct in my book and I disagree with @Prix for the reason I just explained. I checked the `AIX` and `Solaris` man pages as well and they copied the `POSIX` text verbatim (also only mentioning `0 / >0`). Any exit code check seems to be non-portable and guesswork based on the system in question.

Comment: the failure messages you are looking for are in the actual remove file code ...for busybox you could patch http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/libbb/remove_file.c ... for each `if (!(flags & FILEUTILS_FORCE)) {` add an `else{printf("same error message as perror");}` I am sure other implementations would be similar, but if not the busybox version could be built on its own and included.

Comment: I was looking are coreutils for gnu so that's what linux uses for the rm binary.  busybox is an interesting case though.